# How do I save the sort order of a jQueryUI Sortable list into localStorage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, local-storage

I am using the jQueryUI Sortable function for an unordered list.  I would like to save the sorted order into the localstorage. What is the best way to do this?  I was thinking ajax but I'm not sure quite how to do that.

Here is my source code so far.

```
<ul id="wrapper">
    <li class="grid_section" id="grid1">
        <div class="grabber">
            <h2>Grid 1</h2>
        </div><!--/grabber-->
    </li>

    <li class="grid_section" id="grid2">
        <div class="grabber">
            <h2>Grid 2</h2>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="grid_section" id="grid3">
        <div class="grabber">
            <h2>Grid 3</h2>
        </div>                                               
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#wrapper").sortable({
            update: function () {
                var order = $("#wrapper").sortable('toArray').toString();
                 console.log("Sorted : " + order);
                 $("#output").text(order);

                 $.ajax({                         
                     type: "POST",
                     data: "order=" + order,
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function (order) {
                         console.log("Success" + order);
                     },
                     error: function (order) {
                         console.log("Failed" + order);
                     }
                 })
             },
             placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
         }).disableSelection();
      });
  });
```

I can easily see the order and have it output but now I need to store that order in localStorage and have it called when the page loads.  I'm not sure localStorage is the best solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store it in localStorage then there is no need for AJAX, you can just write the value directly yourself in the update function.

```
localStorage.setItem("sortOrder", order)
```

When the page loads, you will need to retrieve the value from localStorage to initialize your list.

```
var order = localStorage.getItem("sortOrder")
```

[HTML5 Web Strorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)